# Apache Commons Daemon - Cannot launch service

Tags: java, windows-services, jvm

I can install, uninstall and run my service as a console application using the Apache Commons Daemon tool. The problem is when I try to run my application as a service, the service status doesn't switch from stopped to running.

Script used to install the service:

```
prunsrv.exe install ServiceName --DisplayName="Some Display Name" --Classpath %cd%\daemon.jar --Install=prunsrv.exe --Jvm=auto --StartMode=jvm --StopMode=jvm --StartClass=Main --StartParams start --StopClass=Main --StopParams stop
```

I'm running the service in windows 8 - 64bits.

Any ideas of what could be the problem?

EDIT:
When running the application in the services.msc and I get the following message:

```
Windows could not start the [Service Name] service on Local Computer
Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

EDIT2:
Tryed in Windows 7-64bits. Same problem.

Comment: "Any ideas of what could be the problem?" - "windows 8 - 64bits" :D (just kidding)

Comment: But seriously ... maybe this answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22093622/982149

Comment: Maybe that's really the problem, I will try in a Windows 7 machine just in case.

Comment: Renamed the files. Same problem.

Comment: Ok, have you tried on Win7, yet? Maybe my not-so-serious comment works out to be more relevant than I thought myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that windows could not find the prunsrv.exe file. In the install folder it must be specified the full path to the executable.